# Can I use C# string interpolation with Linq to SQL

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

While using EF (up to version 6.1.3 at least) assuming you have a class like this:

```
 class Customer
 {
      public string FirstName { get; set; }
      public string LastName { get; set; }
 }
```

if you to get a field `FullName` that is the concatenation of both (`FirstName` and `LastName`) as a field in query result you would have to do something like this:

```
db.Customers.Select(c => new { FullName = c.FirstName + " " + c.LastName })
```

now that there is *String Interpolation* in C# could you do something like this instead

```
db.Customers.Select(c => new { FullName = $"{c.FirstName} {c.LastName}" })
```

this might seem like a trivial example (which it is) but the question remains.

Can I use this out of the box, do I need to make some tricks to get it working or is it sure it **won't** work?

Comment: Umm... why don't you just, you know, try it? You already have all you need to check it out for yourself. Just do it.

Comment: This really comes down to if EF handles `string.Format` as that's what string interpolation is turned into.

Comment: I have just stumbled upon [this article](http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2015/02/24/customizing-string-interpolation-in-c-6/) where they explain some configurations in order to do what i want

Comment: @Luiso Ugh, that article literally shows you how to use string interpolation to create sql that is susceptible to sql injection attacks, not the same as using it in EF that would try to translate code to SQL.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I wouldn't expect so, no. It'll compile down to a `string.Format` call, which I wouldn't *expect* to be supported. If you *really* need the projection to be done in the SQL part, you could test it... but otherwise, as normal, use `AsEnumerable()` when you've finished the part of the query you need to be performed in the database, and then use `Select` after that:

```
var query = db.Customers
              // Project to just the properties we need
              .Select(c => new { c.FirstName, c.LastName })
              // Perform the rest of the query in-process
              .AsEnumerable()
              .Select(c => $"{c.FirstName} {c.LastName}");
```

Answer (score 12):

> could you do something like this instead

Not in the general sense, because string interpolation is just translated to a `string.Format` call, replacing the placeholders with numbers and passing the values as parameters.  So your format gets translated from

```
$"{c.FirstName} {c.LastName}"
```

to

```
string.Format("{0} {1}", c.FirstName, c.LastName);
```

Since not all functionality of `string.Format()` (custom format strings, padding, justification, etc) can be directly translated to SQL, it is not supported.

> do I need to make some tricks to get it working or is it sure it won't work?

I doubt there are any tricks you can do to get it to work in Ling-to-SQL since you are dealing with `string.Format` internally.  You *could* retrieve all of the pieces you need, call `AsEnumerable` to change the context from Linq-to-SQL to Linq-to-Objects, and then use interpolation in a subsequent projection, but in this trivial case using string concatenation is cleaner.