# Concatenate strings inside a linq 'select new object {

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I need to join together two columns inside a LINQ select statement, like this:

```
var result = (from i in db.MyTable
                blah blah ...
                select new MyObject
                {
                    Id = i.MyTableId,
                    ReportedByName = ub.FirstName + ' ' + ub.LastName
                }).First();
```

As I thought it might, `ub.FirstName + ' ' + ub.LastName` throws an error.  How would I work this syntax?

Thanks!

Comment: And what's the error?

Comment: what about `string.concat`? `ReportedByName = string.Concat(ub.FirstName, " ", ub.LastName)`

Comment: `String.Join(" ", ub.FirstName, ub.LastName)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are currently concatenating a string with a `char` value while what you want is to concatenate strings. the string `+` operator is expeciting another `string` and not a `char`. use `" "` instead:

```
ReportedByName = ub.FirstName + " " + ub.LastName
```

Of course other ways way be:

1. [`string.Format`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx) or C# 6.0 syntactic sugar for it of string
   interpolation

   ```
   ReportedByName = string.Format("{0} {1}", ub.FirstName, ub.LastName)
   ReportedByName = $"{ub.FirstName} {ub.LastName}" //syntactic sugar of option above
   ```
2. [`string.join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx) (which is what I'll go for if you have more values)

   ```
   ReportedByName = string.Join(" ", ub.FirstName, ub.LastName)
   ```
3. [`string.Concat`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.concat(v=vs.110).aspx)

   ```
   ReportedByName = string.Concat(ub.FirstName, " ", ub.LastName)
   ```

Because you are in a **linq to entities and not objects in memory** the `string.Join` (and thus also string interpolation) and `string.Format` might not work if you are in a linq that is translated to an sql query. If you want to use those options first retrieve the items to memory (using `ToList()`/`AsEnumerable()` and then use them to concatenate the strings. See Jon's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35158332/can-i-use-c-sharp-string-interpolation-with-linq-to-sql)

Comment: @GiladGreen I checked in console app it is valid in string c = a + ' ' + b; , but probably it is not in linq, if this really solve the problem.

Comment: @mybirthname maybe entity framework can't translate `string+char+string` into a sql statement

Answer (score 2):

If you use C#6 you can do that:

```
= $"{ub.FirstName} {ub.LastName}"
```

I think string interpolation is the easiest to read.

Comment: agree with this being cleaner than doing `+`

Comment: This option won't work - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35158332/can-i-use-c-sharp-string-interpolation-with-linq-to-sql