# Concatenating two strings to one in LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

What is the correct way to retrieve one string by concatenating two strings in a LINQ select operation.

```
var displayName = _db.Users.Where(e => e.Id == appId)
                           .Select(d => new { d.Firstname, d.Lastname })
```

I know there is a way to return a concatenation of those two properties but I've failed to come up with the proper syntax.

Comment: You want first name and last name in one variable?

Comment: Um, `d.FirstName + " " + d.LastName`? It's unclear what you're asking for...

Comment: @Jon Skeet...I tried it with .Select(d => new {d.Firstname + " " + d.Lastname}), shows as error

Comment: @dinotom why would you do `new`? You don't want an anonymous type, you want a string. `.Select(d => d.Firstname + " " + d.Lastname)`

Comment: yep, Leftover from trying new string

Comment: @dinotom But if you do want that as a property of an anonymous class you have to name it `new { FullName = d.Firstname + " " + d.Lastname}`

Comment: @juharr...Thats what I was looking for, but I was using new string {...}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With C# 6 string interpolation, it becomes:

```
var displayName = _db.Users.Where(e => e.Id == appId)
                           .Select(d => $"{d.Firstname} {d.Lastname}");
```

Please note: `.Where` will return an enumeration! You might consider `.FirstOrDefault` or just `.First` instead of the `.Where`.

Comment: Is interpolation supported in the EF store?

Comment: @Igor don't know what `_db.Users` is, so this would be how I start to do it.

Comment: The code in the OP was just psuedo code. I would use FirstorDefault.

Comment: @crashmstr I'd think `_db` strongly suggests the use of EF or some other Linq-To-SQL provider.

Comment: @Igor No it doesn't since string interpolation is just compiled into `string.Format`

Comment: strangely similar to [Can I use string interpolation with Linq to SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35158332/can-i-use-c-sharp-string-interpolation-with-linq-to-sql). But since the OP used pseudo code (not the "real" code) and there is no EF tag, this could still work.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `+` ?

```
.Select(d => d.Firstname + " " + d.Lastname)
```

Comment: String.Concat for string, always...

Comment: haven't used entity framework for a while but not sure string.concat is supported

Comment: @SelmanGenç You haven't missed anything though - it's indeed not supported. I mean, `string.Concat`. `+` is ok.

Comment: @IvanStoev - Based on this documentation I would think it was supported but maybe I am not looking at the right spot? [String Canonical Functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738534(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @ArnaudF. Why, do you just like your code to be more verbose?

Comment: @Igor Actually 3 overloads with 1,2, or 3 `string` arguments are supported. You can see it here [CLR Method to Canonical Function Mapping](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738681(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @ArnaudF.: Um, why?