# SQLite bitwise query to EF Core Linq version?

Tags: c#, linq, sqlite, ef-core-2.0

So, I know my SQL much better than my EF Core linq, so my starting query was just a FromSQL like this:

```
var links = context.PortalLinks.FromSql("SELECT * FROM portal_link WHERE grant_bits & {0} AND linkSet_id={1} ORDER BY sortKey",claim,0).ToList();
```

Now I am trying to translate it into the proper linq style query

```
var links = context.PortalLinks.Where(x => ((x.GrantBits & claim) != 0) && x.LinkSetId == 0).OrderBy(s => s.SortKey);
```

I've come up with this, but I am not happy that I am being forced to explicitly test for !=0 when in SQL that is implicit, and while this instance is harmless I can imagine other cases where there can be a more ... amusing ... mismatch between what I can express in C# and what I want to express in SQL.

I guess, is there some other way to express more idiomatic SQL queries for Linq to parse thats less bound by c#'s own assumptions as to what constitutes valid logic?

Comment: I see you are coming from C/C++. But `int` bitwise `&` operator returning `int` and inability to treat `int` expression implicitly as `bool` expression are CLR idioms, not C# specifics. Also all the query expressions are from `Expression` class which is not C# specific. Lastly, the idea of LINQ is to express in OO way what you need, not in SQL (the query might not target SQL database at all) and let the ORM query translator do the job of expressing it in SQL, something else, or mixture (like EF Core mixed client/server query evaluation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am trying to figure what you mean by *idiomatic*... you can use string interpolation of C# 6.0 inside the query and pass your var:

```
var links = context.PortalLinks.Where(x => ((x.GrantBits & claim) != Int32.Parse($"{myVar}")) && x.LinkSetId == Int32.Parse($"{myVar2}").OrderBy(s => s.SortKey);
```

**Notice that I use string interpolation** as there will be no easy way to achieve this logic with an integer.

you can relate to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35158332/can-i-use-c-sharp-string-interpolation-with-linq-to-sql) for another source of information.

---

**Edit:**

Now that I understand your question I can address your inquiry:

**What you describe isn't going to work with native LINQ functionality** however!

there is this library which will help you extend the dynamic linq and achieve your goal:

[Dynamic LINQ](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library)

Comment: i just mean that in SQL you can expect 'WHERE col & val" to evaluate as true if the bitwise and of col and val is not zero.

Comment: I will mark this correct. All things considered I think it will be more pragmatic to deal with the extra noise in the generated sql to keep the linq query more readable.